# Updated to InnoDb - MySQL Unstable

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have updated several MySQL tables to InnoDb. After doing so, MySQL has become sluggish and the hard drive I have the database on is constantly writing, even though my changes have been completed. Peridoically the CPU will get heavy use, 100% on two cores, but whatever is using them is not registering that us in System Monitor (Debian). Reading the database is possible, but slow. I have not tried writing, as it is obviously busy doing something - but I do not know what.

Digging deeper, I have found that I have a very large ibdata1 file, almost 62GB - I have some large tables in InnoDB, including 16, 10, 9, 1.5 and 1.1 GB; and many smaller.

Does anyone have any idea what may be happening here? Or logs I can look at that might shed some light? I have restarted, but when MySQL comes online, the same thing happens, and has been going on for over an hour. Also, would it be a good idea for me to change some InnoDB tables to MyISSAM? Of the large ones, none require InnoDb for transactions, but some of my smaller ones do (under 50MB).

Comment: I think you should try to optimize innoDB first. Just an opinion

Comment: What would that entail? At the moment I can't really do anything. access to the database is very sluggish, and the hard drive is constantly doing something.

Comment: Can you share more details. How big is the database, what kind of issues are you faces. "Sluggish" and "Doing something" is too generic

Comment: Added more notes above.

Answer (score 1):

Two most important options to start are innodb_buffer_size and innodb_logfile_size. Set former to be as big as your database, but leave at least 4-6G for the OS. 
Optimal logfile size depends on how much you have writes, but something around 256M works for most workloads.